# Unable to analyze dump file in DebugAnalyzer

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, memory-dump

I have a memory dump of a 64-bit w3wp process from a 64-bit machine. When, I open it in WinDbg and analyze it with psscor or sos, it works fine.

However, I am trying to use the [DebugAnalyzer](http://www.debuganalyzer.net/) tool. When I open it and hit the "Run Analysis!" button, here's the error message I see in a dialog-box:

```
---------------------------
Debug Analyzer.NET v2
---------------------------
Unable to detect .NET Runtime (CLR) or Unsupported version
(Hint: Error loading symbol for mscorwks.dll or CLR 1.x)

Verify the following:
- Check if Symbol Path is correct
- You are debugging on the same architecture
  (eg. x86 dump require x86 version of Debug Analyzer)
```

The symbol path is correct (same one WinDbg uses) and I am using 64-bit version of DebugAnalyzer. The .NET version used by the w3wp process is .NET 4.

I cannot find the `mscorwks.dll` anywhere on my machine, but `mscordacwks.dll` is in my symbol path. But, since WinDBG does not seem to need it, I am not sure that is the issue.

Does anyone have experience using this tool or suggested trouble-shooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using Debug Analyzer. The version available for download only supports .NET v2.0 memory dumps. I believe you are testing against a memory dump which has .NET 4.0 loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The message `Unable to detect .NET Runtime (CLR) or Unsupported version` seems to say it all.  I would try Debug Analyzer.NET v2 on other .NET 4.0 applications and see if it it works.  The other line of interest is `You are debugging on the same architecture`.  Is your w3wp.exe a 32-bit or 64-bit process?  Are you using the corresponding version of Debug Analyzer.NET?

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct version of DebugAnalyzer, the architecture matches and the worker process is 64-bit (as I already specified in the description).